# nls.lm - Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'

Tags: r, least-squares, nls

I am trying to fit experimental data to a set of 3 PDEs:

dX/dt = mumax.(S/(Ks+S)).(1-X/Xm).X

dS/dt = -1/Y_x/s * dX/dt - m_s.X - k_LD * dL/dt

dL/dt = -kl * L

I got error No. 6 of 'ftol':

**"Error in chol.default(object$hessian) :
the leading minor of order 6 is not positive definite"**

**"reason terminated: Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'."**

I don't know if the problem lies in the models or the data.

Please find the code below. Thanks

```
library(deSolve)
library(ggplot2)
library(minpack.lm)
library(reshape2)
time <- c(0,2,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42)
X <- c(0.010044683, 0.011653262, 0.013306524, 0.014155496, 0.014959786, 
       0.015630027, 0.016434316, 0.018132261, 0.019651475, 0.021394102, 
       0.023002681, 0.024432529, 0.026085791, 0.027828418, 0.029347632, 
       0.031090259, 0.032698838, 0.034262735, 0.035915996, 0.037569258, 
       0.039311886, 0.040786416, 0.042350313, 0.04409294)
S <- c(0.585443495, 0.537584046, 0.505306743, 0.476368471, 0.464125356, 
       0.451882241, 0.441308642, 0.426283001, 0.403466287, 0.394005698, 
       0.37508452, 0.371188984, 0.353937322, 0.355050332, 0.33668566, 
       0.343920228, 0.328338082, 0.333346629, 0.319433998, 0.314425451, 
       0.309416904, 0.302182336, 0.294391263, 0.288269706)
L <- c(0.372443284, 0.370216418, 0.361865672, 0.362979104, 0.357968657, 
  0.359638806, 0.355741791, 0.345720896, 0.34961791, 0.334029851, 
  0.329019403, 0.334029851, 0.327349254, 0.322338806, 0.319555224, 
  0.315101493, 0.31398806, 0.305080597, 0.302297015, 0.297286567, 
  0.295059701, 0.289492537, 0.282255224, 0.27668806)
data <- data.frame(time,X,S,L)
attach(data)

Hybrid <- function(t,c,parms) {
  k1 <- parms$k1 # mumax
  k2 <- parms$k2 # Ks
  k3 <- parms$k3 # Xm
  k4 <- parms$k4 # Y_x/s
  k5 <- parms$k5 # m_s
  k6 <- parms$k6 # k_LD
  k7 <- parms$k7 # k_l
  r <- numeric(length(c)) 
  r[1] <-  k1 * (c["S"]  / ( k2 + c["S"] )) * c["X"] * (1-c["X"]/k3)  # r[1] = dX/dt = mumax.(S/(Ks+S)).(1-X/Xm).X
  r[2] <- -1/k4 * r[1] - k5 * c["X"] - k6 * r[3] # r[2] = dS/dt = -1/Y_x/s * dX/dt - m_s.X - k_LD * dL/dt
  r[3] <- -k7*c["L"] # dL/dt = -kl * L
  return(list(r))       
}

residuals <- function(parms){
  cinit <- c( X = data[1,2], S = data[1,3], L = data[1,4] )
  t <- sort(unique(c(seq(0, 42, 1), data$time)))
  k1 <- parms[1]
  k2 <- parms[2]
  k3 <- parms[3]
  k4 <- parms[4]
  k5 <- parms[5]
  k6 <- parms[6]
  k7 <- parms[7]
  out <- ode( y = cinit, 
              times = t, 
              func = Hybrid, 
              parms = list( k1 = k1, k2 = k2, k3 = k3, k4 = k4, k5 = k5, k6 = k6, k7 = k7) )
  out_data <- data.frame(out)
  out_data <- out_data[out_data$time %in% data$time,]
  pred_data <- melt(out_data,id.var="time",variable.name="Substance",value.name="Conc")
  exp_data <- melt(data,id.var="time",variable.name="Substance",value.name="Conc")
  residuals <- pred_data$Conc-exp_data$Conc
  return(residuals)
}

parms <- c( k1=0.8,  # mumax
            k2=1.2,  # Ks 
            k3=0.06, # Xm 
            k4=0.05, # Y_x/s
            k5=0.001,# m_s 
            k6=0.05, # k_LD
            k7=0.003)# kl

fitval <- nls.lm(par=parms,fn=residuals)
summary(fitval)
fitval

parest=as.list(coef(fitval))
cinit <- c( X=data[1,2], S=data[1,3], L=data[1,4] )
t<-seq(0, 42, 1)
parms<-as.list(parest)
out<-ode(y=cinit,times=t,func=Hybrid,parms=parms)
out_data<-data.frame(out)
names(out_data)<-c("time","X_pred","S_pred","L_pred")

tmppred<-melt(out_data,id.var=c("time"),variable.name="Substance",value.name="Concentration")
tmpexp<-melt(data,id.var=c("time"),variable.name="Substance",value.name="Concentration")
p<-ggplot(data=tmppred,aes(x=time,y=Concentration,color=Substance,linetype=Substance))+geom_line()
print(p)
p<-p+geom_line(data=tmpexp,aes(x=time,y=Concentration,color=Substance,linetype=Substance))
p<-p+geom_point(data=tmpexp,aes(x=time,y=Concentration,color=Substance))
p<-p+scale_linetype_manual(values=c(0,1,0,1,0,1))
p<-p+scale_color_manual(values=rep(c("red","blue","purple"),each=2))+theme_bw()
print(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if we extract the hessian matrix from the model object we can see:

```
fitval$hessian
#     k1            k2            k3            k4            k5           k6            k7
# k1  3.568033e-09 -1.851988e-09  1.541311e-03 -2.863371e-04  7.213943e-05  0 -3.474817e-10
# k2 -1.851988e-09  9.612743e-10 -8.000189e-04  1.486235e-04 -3.744407e-05  0 -1.831356e-10
# k3  1.541311e-03 -8.000189e-04  1.836024e+03 -2.876605e+02  1.210877e+02  0 -6.701843e-05
# k4 -2.863371e-04  1.486235e-04 -2.876605e+02  4.643049e+01 -1.841829e+01  0 -1.367424e-05
# k5  7.213943e-05 -3.744407e-05  1.210877e+02 -1.841829e+01  8.765142e+00  0 -1.851183e-05
# k6  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0  0.000000e+00
# k7 -3.474817e-10 -1.831356e-10 -6.701843e-05 -1.367424e-05 -1.851183e-05  0  1.215381e+03
```

Notice that k6 row and column are all equal to zero? Thus, your hessian is singular and when the Cholesky decomposition is ran, you get the error:

```
chol(fitval$hessian) # Error in chol.default(fitval$hessian) : the leading minor of order 6 is not positive definite
```

This can happen in a lot of ways. In this case, the error is in the function Hybrid. Notice that you use r[3] to compute r[2] (but r[3] is not yet defined)? If you exchange the lines (compute r[3] first and then r[2]) as in:

```
Hybrid <- function(t,c,parms) {
  k1 <- parms$k1 # mumax
  k2 <- parms$k2 # Ks
  k3 <- parms$k3 # Xm
  k4 <- parms$k4 # Y_x/s
  k5 <- parms$k5 # m_s
  k6 <- parms$k6 # k_LD
  k7 <- parms$k7 # k_l
  r <- numeric(length(c)) 
  r[1] <-  k1 * (c["S"]  / ( k2 + c["S"] )) * c["X"] * (1-c["X"]/k3)  # r[1] = dX/dt = mumax.(S/(Ks+S)).(1-X/Xm).X
  r[3] <- -k7*c["L"] # dL/dt = -kl * L
  r[2] <- -1/k4 * r[1] - k5 * c["X"] - k6 * r[3] # r[2] = dS/dt = -1/Y_x/s * dX/dt - m_s.X - k_LD * dL/dt
  return(list(r))       
}
```

Then, the error disappears:

```
summary(fitval)
# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# k1  1.958e+03  9.348e+06   0.000   0.9998    
# k2  3.738e+03  1.785e+07   0.000   0.9998    
# k3  3.041e-02  1.393e-03  21.835   <2e-16 ***
# k4  1.188e-01  6.311e-02   1.882   0.0644 .  
# k5  3.078e-02  3.795e-01   0.081   0.9356    
# k6 -9.697e-01  5.823e+00  -0.167   0.8683    
# k7  6.626e-03  1.525e-04  43.459   <2e-16 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.005309 on 65 degrees of freedom
# Number of iterations to termination: 37 
# Reason for termination: Conditions for `info = 1' and `info = 2' both hold.
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Ventrilocus. Switching the position of r[3] with r[2] finally delivered the summary of fitval. However, why do I still get ***Reason for termination: Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'***?

Comment: It is not an error. The algorithm needs to decide when the solution converges. Check the help page for nls.lm.control. It states: "ftol:  
non-negative numeric. Termination occurs when both the actual and predicted relative reductions in the sum of squares are at most ftol. Therefore, ftol measures the relative error desired in the sum of squares". If you are not convinced, just ran the example from the nls.lm help page and you will see that summary(nls.out) will also display "Reason for termination: Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'".